# expectation of a function of random variable in two ways

Tags: probability, expectation

Define the following independent random variables $$Y= cos(\theta_1)- cos(\theta_2)$$

Assume $$\theta_1, \theta_2 \sim U[-\pi,\pi]$$
then with convolution we can get $$Y\sim f_Y(y)$$

Now assume that I want to get expected value of function of Y

$$\mathbb{E}[ \frac{1}{G(Y)}]$$

Is the following true
$$\mathbb{E}[ \frac{1}{G(Y)}]=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{1}{G(y)} f_Y(y)= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{G(cos\theta_1-cos\theta_2)} d\theta_1d\theta_2 $$

thanks

Comment: missing something about independence somewhere?

Comment: yes $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are independent. sorry forgot to mention. will edit

Comment: sorry, still need to refine a bit. I think you want the $\theta$s to be independent and identically distributed. After these being defined, you want $Y$ to be a function of these. You want $\frac{1}{G}$ to be integrable over the domain of integration (so, for instance, you want to avoid $G=0$ being a problem). You forgot a $dy$ in the penultimate integral. And, yes, the integrals being equal is "true", from the so-called law of the unconscious statistician http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician